# javascript: append text to textarea performance

Tags: javascript, performance, textarea

I'm currently implementing a system for running build process remotely from browser. One of the tasks is to display build console output which downloads partially by ajax. And here I've faced the problem: I'm trying to output this log to textarea control and the log is quite heavy (may reach 12Mb and more depending on how many targets are building). My concern is about a compatibility of textarea with my requirements. I'm beginning to suspect this is not the best way of displaying so huge amount of info since I've been trying different approaches for appending data to textarea:

```
<textarea id='log'></textarea>

//using jQuery
$("#log").append(data["log"]); <- data["log"] is ajax result
//or classic JS
document.getElementById("log").value += data["log"]
```

the result is always the same: as larger textarea content as longer UI lags (it may entirely freeze for a second or two). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/93bexk59/
```

Hey,

basically - don't use textarea and minimize amount of dom manipulations. 
What you can do? 
1 Use documentFragment API to build parts of DOM out of it
2 Cache data which passes from ajax and drop it on page every N-th items
3 Render the things using async calls, not immediately.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //some render here
}, 0)
```

I've attached an example (jsfiddle).

Hope I understand you correctly, and with this approach (list instead of textarea you have more customization options).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I thought of this. the only reason that's stopping me from using something other than textarea is out-of-the-box resize control that appears in right bottom corner) your example works brilliant. If I don't find any better solution I'll except this one